# Registered user data is not saved to database. Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, roles

I tried to implement role base authentication. Authentication is done correctly. If the user is admin only then he can register a new employee. But the matter is the data put into registration form is not saved to database. Route redirections are correct but data is not saved. I am using builtin auth system of laravel 5.2.

```
Route:: get('/register',['middleware'=> 'roles', function(){

    return view('auth.register');
}]);
```

middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->user()==null)
        {
            return redirect('/login');

        } 
        if (!$request->user()->isAdmin()){
            return redirect('books');
        }

        return $next($request);

    }
}
```

User Model:

```
  public function roles(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role','roles_users', 'user_id', 'role_id');
    }
    public function isAdmin() {
        return in_array(2, $this->roles()->pluck('role_id')->all());
    }
```

if I remove the middleware then the registered data is saved properly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. In built in AuthController there is a constructor with predefined middleware. Deleted it. My code works as I wanted.